# getting empty results using URL variable from rewritten URL for my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting

Hi I have a site that I have launched and my news articles are not showing up, I am using a url variable to determine which article to load onto a dynamic php page.

My site is www.coverforce.com.au and the problem links are for the news articles showing on the index page in the bottom right hand corner.

My query code is as follows:

```
 $totalRows_variablearticles = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $totalRows_variablearticles = $_GET['id']; 
  }
mysql_select_db($database_newsDBconnection, $newsDBconnection);
$query_variablearticles = sprintf("SELECT * FROM NewsArticles, NewsArticleCategories, NewsArticlePhotos, NewsPhotos, NewsCategories WHERE NewsArticles.id = %s AND NewsArticles.id = NewsArticleCategories.newsArticleID AND NewsArticles.id = NewsArticlePhotos.newsArticleID AND NewsArticlePhotos.newsPhotoID = NewsPhotos.id AND NewsArticleCategories.newsCategoryID = NewsCategories.id", GetSQLValueString($totalRows_variablearticles, "int"));
$variablearticles = mysql_query($query_variablearticles, $newsDBconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_variablearticles = mysql_fetch_assoc($variablearticles);
$totalRows_variablearticles = mysql_num_rows($variablearticles);
```

My htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?test\.html$ test.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule insurance-news/news/(.*)/(.*)/$ insurance-news/news.php?$1=$2

rewritecond %{http_host} ^coverforce.com.au [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.coverforce.com.au/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

This is the code I am using to load the content onto the page

```
<h1><?php echo $row_variablearticles['headline']; ?></h1>
    <p>Posted:<?php echo $row_variablearticles['publishDate']=substr($row_variablearticles['publishDate'],0,-8); ?></p>
    <p><br /> 
      <?php echo $row_variablearticles['text']; ?></p>
```

Any help you can provide would be fantastic - my boss is going to chop my head off if I don't fix soon lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .htaccess you have:

```
RewriteRule insurance-news/news/(.*)/(.*)/$ insurance-news/news.php?$1=$2
```

Your code is looking for a get of 'id', so surely that line should be

```
RewriteRule insurance-news/news/(.*)/(.*)/$ insurance-news/news.php?id=$2
```

Do a print_r($_GET); (or dump to a log file if the site is live) and check what it shows.

Comment: Thanks robbie - this is what it shows when I put the print_r($_GET); `code`Array
(
    [news/start-your-own-business-insurance] => 800479715
)`code`.

Comment: Does this mean it is getting my id which is that end number? Or is it thinking that the whole news/start-your-own-business etc. thing is my id?

Comment: The $_GET is as I'd epxect. Please change your .htaccess to what I said in the asnwer and you'll see $_GET = Array([id]=>800479715); which, I presume is what you want?

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept the answer so others don't waste time trying to solve it for you (plus I get the credit :)). Cheers.